How to check body for Valid JSON in Bruno lang?
I have been using Postman for API Testing. I am trying out bruno at the moment. (https://docs.usebruno.com/). One thing I am doing in Postman is testing if my response is valid JSON. I haven't found any information about how to do this with the bru lang.
Postman:
pm.test("Response is valid JSON", function () {
    pm.response.to.be.json;
});

Bruno:
test("Response should be JSON", function() {
  const data = res.getBody();
  expect(res.getBody()).to. ??
});

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I did not find this in the docs but after all I could figure it out by looking at the assertions:
test("Response body should be JSON", function() {
  const data = res.getBody();
  expect(res.body).is.json;
});

I were also able to add a check for XML Bodys which might be insteresting for someone:
test("Response body should be XML", function() {
  const data = res.getBody();
  expect(res.body).startsWith("<?xml");
});


For future reference, Bruno has a list of inbuilt libraries that can be used for various things and this list includes ChaiJS for testing. Perhaps checking the docs there would be helpful
